# How to append a list element to each row in a pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, string-concatenation, series

I have the following pandas Series, whereby each row is a long string with no spaces. It is shaped `(250,)` (i.e. there are 250 rows)

```
import pandas as pd
sr1 = pd.Series(...)

                                                     0  
0    abdcadbcadcbadacbadbdddddacbadcbadadbcadbcadad...  
1    cacacdacadbdcadcabdcbadcbadbdabcabdbbbbbacdbac...  
2    bbbbbcadcacddabcadbcdabcbaddcbadcbadbcadbcaaba...  
3    acdbcdacdbadbadcbdbaaaacbdacadbacaddcabdacbdab...  
....
```

I have a list of 250 strings which I would like to append to the beginning of each of the rows.

```
list_of_strings = ["prefix1", "prefix2", "prefix3", ...., "prefix250"]
```

How does one append each element in `list_of_strings` to the corresponding row in `sr1`? The resulting Series should look like this:

```
                                                    0  
0    prefix1    abdcadbcadcbadacbadbdddddacbadcbadadbcadbcadad...  
1    prefix2    cacacdacadbdcadcabdcbadcbadbdabcabdbbbbbacdbac...  
2    prefix3    bbbbbcadcacddabcadbcdabcbaddcbadcbadbcadbcaaba...  
3    prefix4    acdbcdacdbadbadcbdbaaaacbdacadbacaddcabdacbdab...  
....
```

My first thought was to try something like:

```
sr1.insert(0, "prefixes", value = list_of_strings)
```

But this throws the error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'insert'`. One could convert `sr1` to a pandas DataFrame with `sr1 = sr1.to_frame()`, and the previous `.insert()` will result in a DataFrame with two columns.

In python, we can concatenate strings with a specified delimiter as follows:

```
first = "firstword"
second = "secondword"
combined = "    ".join([first, second])
## outputs 'firstword    secondword'
```

I'm not sure how this is down with a pandas Series. Perhaps `.apply('    '.join)` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first create `Series` from `list` and then add double [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) or `+` - one for whitespace and another for `s`:

```
s = pd.Series(['a','b','c'])
list_of_strings = ["prefix1", "prefix2", "prefix3"]

print (pd.Series(list_of_strings, index=s.index).add(' ').add(s))
#same as
#print (pd.Series(list_of_strings, index=s.index)+ ' ' + s)
0    prefix1 a
1    prefix2 b
2    prefix3 c
dtype: object
```

Another solution with [`cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
print (pd.Series(list_of_strings, index=s.index).str.cat(s, sep=' '))
0    prefix1 a
1    prefix2 b
2    prefix3 c
dtype: object
```

Solution with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), but need `DataFrame` - by constructor or by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame({'prefix':list_of_strings, 'vals':s}).apply(' '.join, axis=1))
0    prefix1 a
1    prefix2 b
2    prefix3 c
dtype: object
```

---

```
print (pd.concat([pd.Series(list_of_strings, index=s.index), s], axis=1)
         .apply(' '.join, axis=1))
0    prefix1 a
1    prefix2 b
2    prefix3 c
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Use + operator, it will concatenate strings automatically.

```
pd.Series(list_of_strings) + "    " + sr1
```

Comment: This answer works, but one still needs to use a delimiter, i.e. `pd.Series(list_of_strings) + "    " + sr1`

Answer (score 1):

You can makes a series of your prefixes, then just add the two series together:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(['a'*10,'b'*10,'c'*10])

s1
# returns:
# 0    aaaaaaaaaa
# 1    bbbbbbbbbb
# 2    cccccccccc


s2 = pd.Series(['pre1', 'pre2', 'pre3'])

s2+s1
# returns:
# 0    pre1aaaaaaaaaa
# 1    pre2bbbbbbbbbb
# 2    pre3cccccccccc
```

Comment: This answer works, but one still needs to use a delimiter, i.e. `sr1 + "    " + sr2`

Answer (score 1):

How about just turn the list of prefixes into a series of length 250, then add them.

```
sr0 = pd.Series(list_of_strings)
sr1 = sr0 + sr1
```

Comment: This answer works, but one still needs to use a delimiter, i.e. `sr1 = sr0 + "    " + sr1`